# Rspec pass configuration options in terminal command

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I would like to pass config options when running `rspec` from terminal, as opposed to setting them in a file that `rspec` reads from.

My `spec_helper` specifies `config.order='random'`, so I need to override this.

The use case is generating a command to use in a rake task (to generate documentation).

I've tried:

```
rspec spec/ --config.order default
```

but `--config` is an invalid option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rspec spec --order default
```

Generally most of the command line options take the form `--<option-name> <value>`. See `rspec --help` for the details.

Comment: Ah nice! The help output doesn't say anything about this format, although you're right, that seems to follow the pattern :) Thank you!